# Height to absolute div

Tags: jquery, css, html, absolute

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw6kM/25/)

```
var element=$("#outer"); // element is a jQuery object
var max=0;
element.children().each(function(index, child) {
    child=$(child);
    var childPos=child.position();
    var childMax=childPos.top+child.outerHeight();
    if(childMax>max) {
        max=childMax;
    }
});
element.css({height: max+'px'});
```

can anyone please add border to `#outer` div without giving fix height ? :/

I try to use jquery but it won't work. Kindly provide me any working example if possible.

Comment: Sounds like more of a css problem than a strictly Javascript problem.

Comment: You should also be aware that `.children` only gets the immediate children of the element, not grand children or great grand children and so on. So your `elemet.children()` is only returning one result: the `ul` that is the immediate child of your `div`. I don't think that's what you intended. Try `.find("*")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to put the border around the content in `box2` which is actually overflowing (meaning it's height property won't reflect the height of it's content).

Change the CSS to be `height:auto`:

```
#box1, #box2 {
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Then change your selector for the each:

```
element.find('*').each( function(index, child) { 
    //... 
});
```

So you get the element `box2` in the iteration because it's not a direct child of `outer`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw6kM/28/)

**Update: Alternative Solution**

If you want to keep your CSS as you originally wrote it, you can find the `scrollHeight` of the DOM element and use that to determine the height of the content inside of it in the case of an overflow.

Change this line:

```
var childMax=childPos.top+child.outerHeight();
```

To this:

```
var childMax=childPos.top+child[0].scrollHeight;
```

[Alternative Solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw6kM/31/)

Comment: @StunomaticWay Remove the `childPos.top` from this line: `var childMax=childPos.top+child[0].scrollHeight;` on your website and it should work fine. You don't need to add the top position when figuring out the max height.

Answer (score 0):

I added a border here:

```
#outer {
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
width: 200px;
background: #aaa;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

It now has border.
what do you want to achieve?
perhaps you want it to have a border, and to contain all of its child elements?